# Extreamly Slow Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, performance

I having a Wordpress site which take more than 5 sec to load out, and is extremely slow performance.

I tried everything i can to speed it up but still no luck.

Any recommended solution for me ?

Here is my Website URL

[Stormbodykits.com](https://www.stormbodykits.com/)

Comment: 5 seconds is a bit more than just slow, your either experiencing a network realted issue or dealing with an extremely slow/overwhelmed host. You need to post more details to know for sure

Comment: Site seems OK. still you need to check with the cache and extra installed plugins.

Comment: Seems alright now. It's possible someone else you're sharing your host box with is hogging system resources. If you can ssh into the box, login in and just type "top". You should see a rolling load average at the top of the screen. To quite out of "top" just press "q". Learn more about load averages here: https://www.tecmint.com/understand-linux-load-averages-and-monitor-performance/ If your load average is high, contact godaddy and ask them if there is a user on your box hogging resources. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the Network tab in Dev tools show that this is not limited to PHP/WordPress but is equally effecting all static content such as images, JavaScript and CSS. This is a hosting issue, either too small of a virtual host or overly saturated shared hosting. If your hosting the site yourself you may need to upgrade your upload speeds through your ISP. Long story short, WordPress is not generating this content. The time is being spent fetching from disk (or memory in some cases) and then sending the resources to user. The most likely bottleneck in this scenario is the network when looking at full seconds rather than milliseconds, especially on a site serving only a few connected users at a given time.